Optimizing Miller-Rabin by selecting bases calculated from the number to test
(First to say, I am not a mathematician, so possibly this has all been well known for 1000 years and boring for you.
Tell me if so...)
I tried to optimize the Miller-Rabin prime test by selecting better bases, calculated from the number to prove.
The question is, is the method described here to improve the selection of bases for Miller-Rabin useful? If not, why?
Quick:
I am NOT suggesting that the tests used today are not safe, especially not MR+Lucas! My idea was to improve the filter ability of MR itself. I found a pattern in the factors of pseudoprimes that are very efficient "liars", passing many bases. And I make use of this factor relationship to filter exactly these liars. I can drop the worst-case probability form (1/4)^t per random MR to about ~(1/14)^t. I am not reinventing the wheel, just using an idea to improve MR independently of the existence of Lucas.
I think the factor pattern described here is interesting, it may already be known, but I am just making use of it. (And the prime relationship described here could be used to manipulate RSA keys, but the first focus is on improving the MR filter.)
Here I speak about filtering hard Miller-Rabin pseudoprimes, a hard pseudoprime is one that can pass many bases.
The work is mainly statistical with some algebra, without deep knowledge of prime-number theory.
I searched hard pseudoprimes in a number range of 2^64, in a small window of 65536 bases. Without strong hardware, this took several months of statistical analysis.
The data set for the research comes from here:
https://miller-rabin.appspot.com/
2-SPRP-2-to-64.zip
Analysis:
Some pseudoprimes are harder to filter than others, some pass many bases. Obviously, we want to filter the hardest pseudoprimes first.
Like everyone, I first tried to find the best static filtering base, such as 15, 735, or 9375.
Then I tried to use static bases that are particularly efficient at filtering hard pseudoprimes. This was not very successful, with only little benefit.
But the best way is to define the base according to the number to prove.
So I made statistics and found that particularly hard pseudoprimes passing many bases have a specific form.
They mostly have only two factors, and these factors have a relationship. In a number range of 2^64 pre-filtered with base 2, I found only very few (<2000) super hard pseudoprimes with three factors, and none with more.
Relationship:
The pseudoprime relationship is defined like this, by the smaller factor.
a = smaller factor
b = bigger factor
z = a * b = pseudoprime
d:m = relationship, for example 1:2
(a-1) / (b-1) = (d / m)  ,  1:{2, 3, 4, 5} to filter relationships

z = a * ((a - 1) * m / d + 1)
z = 49141 pseudoprime
a = 157   smaller factor
b = 313   bigger factor
d = 1     relationship 1:2
m = 2

In words, having a hard pseudoprime with the relationship 1:2 means that if both factors are subtracted by 1 and the bigger factor is divided by the smaller, the smaller factor is exactly 2, 3, 4, 5, etc., times smaller than the bigger factor.
This can be used to check if such a relationship exists, to filter specifically the hardest pseudoprimes with two factors.
Filter:
We filter specifically hard pseudoprimes with two factors and a relationship of 1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 1:5, the rest are not as hard. (see images below)
reorder to a = smaller factor:
a = (Sqrt(z * 4*m*d + (m - d)^2) - m - d) / (2 * m) + 1
Simplified if m=2 and d=1, relationship 1:2:
a = (Sqrt(z * 8 + 1) - 3) / 4 + 1
More simplified for a SqrtPerfect test:
c = Sqrt(z * 8 + 1)
This can be reduced to a square perfect test, if the square has no remainder, it is composite.
t = SqrtPervect(z * 8 + 1)
Reduced further (we deal with integer math and round down):
a = Sqrt(z / m) + 1
a = Sqrt(z / 2) + 1     for 1:2
In words, a simple calculation like Sqrt(z/2)+1 could find the smaller factor if the relationship is 1:2.
157 = Sqrt(49141 / 2) + 1     integer math round down
Example:
Miller-Rabin:
z = 7703244732950872381   pseudoprime
a = 1962555061   smaller factor
b = 3925110121   bigger factor
r = 1:2 = (1962555061 - 1) / (3925110121 - 1)   relationship
m = 2
d = 1
h = 0.260 ~ 17015 / 65536   hardness, found/checked, pseudoprime passes 26% of bases
t = true  = SquarePerfect((7703244732950872381 / 2) + 1)   is composite
t = false = Miller-Rabin(7703244732950872381, Sqrt(7703244732950872381 / 2) + 1)   is composite

Example of a super hard pseudoprime with three factors:
6019396925640761251 = 185371 * 926851 * 35034931
Passes 20642 of 65536 bases, 31%

Conclusion:
It shows that such calculated bases are better filters than the best-known static numbers, even if they are not a true factor.
We use not only a SqrtPerfect test, but a Miller-Rabin to filter all potential relationships plus many more pseudoprimes.
I would suggest optimizing all prime tests so that the small relationships are checked to filter all hard pseudoprimes with two factors. Super hard pseudoprimes with more factors are extremely rare and cannot be filtered anymore with this method, because of the combinatorics between the three or more factors.
(A question is too, can hard pseudoprimes be constructed intentionally, which can pass easy Miller-Rabin and Lucas-Selfridge tests at the same time?)
With the combination of a Lucas-Selfridge test, the prime test would be very strong (AKS is 100% safe but still too slow for cryptographic large numbers.)
Optimization:
MillerRabin(n, 2)  // 2 as a base filters well, avoid in case Sqrt(), and tested in 2^64 with Lucas-Selfridge
MillerRabin(n, Sqrt(n / 2) + 1)
MillerRabin(n, Sqrt(n / 3) + 1)
MillerRabin(n, Sqrt(n / 4) + 1)
MillerRabin(n, Sqrt(n / 5) + 1)
Some MillerRabin(n, Random(n - 5) + 3)
LucasSelfridge(n)

I found a few texts online where some people detected this factor relationship of hard pseudoprimes too. But I found nobody actually trying to use it practically.
Yes, we perform some slow Sqrt(), but with the benefit of filtering specifically the hard pseudoprimes. And we need far fewer Random() tests.
Yes, Lucas-Selfridge is a very good partner with Miller-Rabin, but we can still improve it.
LucasSelfridge actually has a similar factor relationship pattern, Miller-Rabin a-1:b-1 LucasSelfridge a+1:b-1.
This is why Miller-Rabin and LucasSelfridge complement each other well, each test filtering pseudoprimes with a different factor pattern. There are very few pseudoprimes passing both tests, none in 2^64, but it is proven that there are infinitely many pseudoprimes passing both tests.
5777 = 53 * 109    LucasSelfridge pseudoprime
(53+1) * (109-1) = 1/2

Statistics:
(The images are not shown, click on the links to see the statistical images.)
Here are some statistics. The hardness is estimated with an RM test using the first 65536 bases of all pseudoprimes in 2^64 after base 2 filtering.
The peaks show that the pseudoprimes and their hardness are grouped according to their factor relationships.
X = hardness in %, Passes / MaxAmount
Y = normalized amount of pseudoprimes found in this specific hardness.
Image: Relationship grouping and count and hardest
The peaks show that, for example, the 1:2 factor relationship is the hardest, and all pseudoprimes in this hardness have exactly this form.
There are some super-hard pseudoprimes with 3 factors, but so few that they do not show up on a linear scale.
Image: Filter with a good static base 9375
Image: Filter with 1:2
Image: Filter with 1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 1:5
The calculated bases filter step by step all hard pseudoprimes. The few remaining peaks are super-hard pseudoprimes with 3 factors.
End:
Anybody know more? Is this a useful optimization, or am I missing something?
Progress:
1.
I learned something more. Keep in mind, I am a hobbyist and not a trained mathematician. (Otherwise, I would write a paper about it and not ask questions. ;-) I got the info that my test is related to the "weighted Fermat attack," and Pomerance wrote about such numbers 40 years ago. I found these hard pseudoprimes when I made my lookup-table prime check and found the pattern of the hard PPs. I tried to reduce the lookup-table size somehow, with a filter for these hard PPs. And I speculated about an improvement of the MR test in general and a potential attack where the relationships could compromise RSA keys. Thanks much for all suggestions!
Here are some links for lookup-table prime checks where the method described here could have a use to reduce the lookup table, maybe for checks > 2^64.
https://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1326/020-Forisek.pdf
https://sourceforge.net/projects/isprime64/
https://github.com/JASory/machine-prime
A paper about prime test issues.
https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/749
Carl Pomerance, Selfridge, Wagstaf, The Pseudoprimes to 25 • 109
https://sci-hub.se/10.1090/s0025-5718-1980-0572872-7
2.
Fermat attack: I rediscovered an attack method that is already known. We cannot blindly trust a product just because cryptography is written on it. The method described here can not only be used to filter specially hard pseudoprimes but to discover intentionally manipulated RSA keys, like what I speculated. It would be possible to use a range away from the relationship to hide such a manipulated RSA key better. It is clear that the Fermat attack only works with compromised software. A malicious party could put such a manipulated RSA key generator into different products. The keys would look genuine, but the relationship gives this party access to the data, they use a relationship plus some needed search in a range, and hide the manipulation. (But my idea was to improve lookup tables for one-try prime-check and maybe for MR.)
(That software, even open-source software, and even crypto standards could be intentionally manipulated is proven with, for example, the random generator Dual_EC_DRBG. If this would become a standard, all software using it would have a backdoor in their crypto system, independent of the used crypto algorithms.)
Fermat attack, two primes must be relatively close to each other, 1:1 relationship:
"Flawed RSA key generation algorithms have been found multiple times before."
https://fermatattack.secvuln.info
https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/026
https://badkeys.info
Weighted Fermat attack, two primes can have a relationship like described here: 1:m, d:m, d:m±a, or any other.
Interestingly, I have not quickly found any publication about this until now.
It could be possible that researchers find more compromised keys if they search for other relationships than only 1:1. It seems not many search for them now, and the search would be more extensive, and the relationship would hide them better than the simple 1:1.
3.
More clarification, the way I try to filter specially hard pseudoprimes with a square root test leads to a filter that can detect Carmichael numbers. The method described here filters two-factor pseudoprimes that have Carmichael-like qualities but with only two factors. The method works for two-factor hard pseudoprimes, but for pseudoprimes with more factors, it needs a range of tests. I am not aware if there is a method to detect Carmichael numbers without factorization. But like for the two-factor numbers with Carmichael qualities, there are statistically relevant patterns that could be analyzed and used as a filter.
Some people try to detect Carmichael numbers, now the question is how to do this faster than a combination of Fermat and Miller-Rabin (All Carmichael numbers pass Fermat but not Miller-Rabin).
Check if a number is Carmichael
To filter a Carmichael number with 3 factors, you would do something like this with the same root method:
n = 6019396925640761251 = 185371 * 926851 * 35034931
a = 185371
b = 926851
c = 35034931
s = 5 = (b-1) / (a-1)
t = 189 = (c-1) / (a-1)
a = root3(n / s / t) + 1

4.
An example of how the Extended or Weighted Fermat Attack/Backdoor could be used with the method described here in RSA. (This possibility showed up during the development of the method, with the intention to improve the Miller-Rabin filter.)
Classical Fermat attack/backdoor:
For the classical Fermat backdoor, an attacker would select the first prime truly randomly, and then search for a second prime very close or in a small range to the first one. This backdoor is easy to find, and software has been found to have such weak keys, as https://badkeys.info has proven. And it can be speculated that some are not mistakes but were intentionally created. The backdoor is unprotected because not much searching needs to be done to find the two primes.
Two primes are almost equal in size
n ~ 4'294'967'296
a ~ b ~ sqrt(n) ~ 65'536
Search for the two primes around a.

Extended Fermat attack/backdoor:
For the extended Fermat backdoor, an attacker would select the first prime truly randomly, and then make the second prime dependent on a specific secret relationship, for example, 13:17. The relationship would be the protection mechanism for the backdoor. If the relationship uses large numbers, it provides cryptographically relevant protection for the backdoor because of the combinatoric possibilities of the secret relationship between the two primes.
n ~ 4'294'967'296
a ~ 57'309 ~ sqrt(n*13/17)
b ~ 74'944 ~ n / a
Search for the two primes around a and b.

If such backdoors could exist, they would probably be in closed environments, like hardware (e.g., printers or chip cards), or in closed software. A plausible-deniability excuse like "it was only a mistake and an implementation error" would no longer work.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

If we have an odd number p >= 3, then the Miller-Rabin test with a random base a, 2 <= b <= p-2, will tell you with probability >= 3/4 that p is composite if it is composite and tells you nothing for primes, and for less than a quarter of the composites. If you do this for say 64 different bases a, then if p is composite, the chances that you were never told in 64 tests is less than 2^-256, so we assume with good justification that p is prime.
Now no composite number p is particularly good at “hiding”. Every time you do a test with a random base a, chances that p is identified as composite are less than 1/4. Now if you pick fixed bases a = 2, 3, 5, 7 there will be composite numbers that are not detected. But if you pick different bases that detect them, then suddenly you have other composite numbers that go undetected.
For RSA, you need for example two 1024 bit primes. A random integer of that size is prime with probability about 1/700, so you pick on an average 700 random 1024 bit integers until you find a prime. You want to discard composites as fast as possible, and then you end up with one number that is likely a prime and repeat the tests until you are sure enough.
The numbers you pick for testing must be random. If they are not, then an attacker could find which numbers you were testing and reconstruct your primes. So the numbers must also be under your control. Even if there were numbers that are harder to test, you would only pick them randomly.
To discard composites fast, you would first check if p is divisible by 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 etc. You can very quickly reject all but say 100 out of 700 numbers by doing a divisibility test. Then Miller-Rabin with a = 2, 3, 5, 7 will leave 25, 6, 1.5, less than half a composite number. And now the 64 tests that you want to do to make very sure you have a prime, you have to do those anyway.
There is an important thing about the bases: You will calculate a^(p-1) modulo (p-1). The powers will be 1024 but numbers. When you calculate this power, squaring is a full 1024x1024 bit multiplication, taking long time. If a is a small number, say 64 bit, then multiplying by a is much faster. So you don’t want a very large a. (For random 1024 bit p, you will need 1024 squaring and 512 multiplications by a, so this saves significant time).

"no composite number p is particularly good at hiding". This is wrong, this is the point of the discussion here. Check the statistics. Numbers with specific described relations between the factors are better then others in hiding.

If you check {2,3,5,7} first and then do 64 random. What speaks against to use {sqrt(n/2)+1, sqrt(n/3)+1, sqrt(n/4)+1, sqrt(n/5)+1} and then use less random? sqrt is fast compared with MR. (we forget for a moment that lucas exists, to get the head free for the idea.)

Sqrt is going to be considerably faster than a Miller-Rabin test. I use the relation you observed to eliminate the composites directly using the sqrt, and then follow it with some base (usually the first non-quadratic residue as described by Narayanan). This is both faster and stronger, since the form check eliminates the hard examples so you can then select a base that is stronger against weaker forms.
To answer your question about if it is easy to produce the strong examples. It is. All you need to do is generate a list of primes and then calculate another prime of the form (p-1)*a + 1 and then multiply it with p (where a is small integer less than some bound, I pick usually 64). Because you only need to check up to pi(sqrt(n)) pairs, this can be done relatively quickly. A very convenient fact of the set of these numbers is that constructing a list of bases that eliminate these semiprimes will very likely eliminate all other composites.
As an aside I have been working on very similar lines as you, trying instead to produce a generalised library for various computations of fermat pseudoprimes and selection of bases. Like your project it is only currently reliable for 64-bit integer (although it does support some 128-bit calculations), but it is extensible, has fast arithmetic, and can avoid extreme usage of RAM (and of course parallelised). I haven't done much statistics, since I am waiting to develop fast calculations to replicate the hardest research. (Note that your Sqrt check function is implemented as SPK filter and your MillerRabin base selection as SFsqr)

Tanks much for the answer! i will check the info.
Sorry. I was not clear whit the question, yes it is very easy to construct a hard base for MR or Lucas. The right question was, for both of them at the same time. If a PP can be constructed fitting (a-1):(b-1) MR and (a+1):(b-1) Lucas, the change is to find a PP witch can pass the Baillie–PSW test. Non found jet. I corrected the Text: (A question is too, can hard pseudo primes be constructed intentionally, witch can pass easy Miller-Rabin and LucasSelfridge at the same time?)

Any idea why nobody use this optimization? it is very simple in math and fast in use.
I actually use first 4 MRs whit 1:{2,3,4,5} because i detected that this bases are very efficient for filtering. But you are maybe right to use only sqrt, i not checked jet what is the bigger gain. I should actually subtract that PPs where the base is a factor, to measure the efficiency correctly. i have not done this jet.

Do you found a way to filter hard PPs with 3 factory? The relationship is more tricky, and it needs a qubik-root. You know any hard PPs with more then 3 factors? in a room of 2^64 i not found 1 with more then 3 factors. i found less then 1200 with 3 factors, to few to get a clear picture. (I am actually very happy the somebody understand the idea!)

The sqrt check works because you are calculating one of the factors and using it as the base, this guarantees that the fermat test (even the weak version) will always fail because gcd(a,n) /= 1. You can see this if you check 2 and 3 with a base-6 fermat test, it will declare them composite. The 3 factor composites you are referring to are Carmichael numbers of the form pqr where p q and r are all primes that have a remainder of 3 mod 4. Unfortunately each factor can have much greater variation than the strong semiprimes. So an equivalent calculation is entirely unfeasible.

I haven't found a strong BPSW composite either, and I ran it against the strong semiprimes less than 2^66. Besides that I have done no work on that problem.

"Why nobody use that optimisation"- 1. It's relatively obscure and probably not know outside of mathematics, it is however mentioned in Pomerance's paper "The Pseudoprimes to 25*10^9". So this has been known for around 40 years. 2. The majority of sophisticated primality testing programs are geared towards cryptography which has strict calculation time requirements, a shortcutting like this would possibly allow a timing attack. 3. Even if you are aware of this algorithm it is a fair amount of work to properly implement and show that it is correct. For most developers MR is the final word.

Tanks, as a hobbits with no mathematical training, i have not know about Pomerance's paper, i missed even the terminology to search with. I will see if i can understand it.

Timing attack: I would speculate that in a situation where we search a prime for a example RSA code, a timing attack should not be a problem. Because if the key is generated, the sqrt method will not be part in the usage of the generated key in RSA. Timing could be used maybe if a prime is generated to be used rite on time. but a attacker still can not know how many numbers are tested to fine a prime. (and sqrt is only a pre filter before the slower MR.)

... "$30 for a number which is both an spsp(2) and an lpsp()" i think the reward should be a bit higher :-)

I notice that you are looking at hashtable computation, incase you didn't notice I have already publicly surpassed those calculations and provide algorithms to do so in the F-Analysis library I linked (I don't have enough reputation to comment outside of my post). Note that GPU is not necessary, I suspect they were using weak hardware combined with slow algorithms.

Tanks for the hint, i have only taken a quick lock in F-Analysis and then live has called attention. I will need some time there because i don't know Rust a all, i code all in C#. I found isprime64 when i searched the base math for my research, like most fastest ModPow for 64 without ASM (sadly in c#) etc. I started actually the research because of the hash table method, when i detected the hard PPs. and i use https://github.com/clSharp/Cloo for OpenCL. The GPU is used to create the hash table. it is very time intensive. for using it you don't need hash tables anymore.

But if you have a method more efficient then 3 MR with hash table for a 1-try deterministic 64bit prime check, this is very interesting. (You see, i learn everything practically on my own, no math uni background, so i didn't know how useful or useless my question here is. I rediscovered what Pomerance hast put in paper 40 years ago.)

In case you have a Lucas pseudo prime dataset source op to 2^64, i would be interested, i not found any.

... i can not even correct a text here... it is not "for using it you don't need hash tables anymore." i meant >>  "for using the result hash table you don't need GPU anymore."

isprime64 has a dataset for all 2^64 SPRP. I search one for LPRP. (But not right now, some when later if i have time. the motivation to do heavy statistics in not very high anymore.)

(this is off topic here but anyway...) OK i checked just fast, core_primality() in machine-prime. FERMAT_BASE locks exactly like the hash table method i use. I use for 32b byte[1024] and 64b ulong[8192].
But i not understand Rust well. You say you found a faster way without hash table?

(... I have no problem with the off topic talk! i found it interesting. but i am new here, it is my first question, and it seams the rules here are pretty restrictive.)

There is no faster way than a hashtable. Machine-prime uses either a BPSW or a 2-base MR (via conditional compilation).  Using the slightly faster Euler-Plumb test a BPSW test can at best run in 2.45t compared to a fermat test, but the hashtable runs in 1.95t. This is the fastest known test for the interval. One could use a single test but that would require quite a lot of precomputation.

Yes, you must then deal with the entire 2^64, not only with ~32mio numbers to create it, if you not use at least base 2, and the hash table would be probably big. I not get all Pomerance wrote so fast, so next is maybe know already too. I found some few patterns in the 3 factor hard PPs. smallest and medium factor often have 5 9 13 2.3_ 17 ... relations, in case some one would like to create them. but i think surely mathematicians know this... tanks much!
